# How do I get json from url in smart contracts?

Tags: rust, smartcontracts, solana

My NFT-tokens metadata are in URL. I want to get content of the url which is in json format, after that convert to a object that I can use for making NFT-Tokens.

In the following, there is a part of my smart contact which show a function for generating MetaData URL Daynamicly. I call it in another function and get current token URI. After that I pass this url to get_token_metadata for geting the URL json data. I tested diffrenct libraries like http,reqwest,curl. However I couldn't success since these libraries need a "async" function which  I didn't know how to develop it on Smart Contract.

```
pub fn get_token_url(&mut self) -> String {
    let s1 = "url".to_string();
    let s2 = self.counter.to_string();
    let s3 = format!("{}{}.json", s1, s2);
    println!("{}", s3.to_string());
    return s3.to_string();
}


pub fn get_token_metadata(url: String) {
   // how do I develop this functions?
}
```

Clearly, How can I get URL json data, and How can I convert to json and object?

Comment: If you don't need/want async, you can use the blocking version of the APIs. [`reqwest` has one](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.11.4/reqwest/blocking/index.html), the others likely do as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer is "you can't". On-chain programs have no access to the outside world, so you cannot use things like `Http` or `Reqwest` in your program.  This allows the chain to reach consensus on the state of the ledger -- if every node has to query the outside world, consensus would be practically impossible.

To resolve your issue, you have to rethink your solution, likely getting the data off-chain and passing it in to your program.

Comment: I understood. We can set "Token URI" by "ERC721" on Ethereum. Do we have "ERC721" or something else like that  on solana?

Comment: The closest thing to ERC721 is a combination of a Mint with only 1 token: https://spl.solana.com/token#example-create-a-non-fungible-token

With the Token Metadata program: https://docs.metaplex.com/#token-metadata